# ng-show not showing/hiding HTML List after variable value change

Tags: angularjs

I have recently started building some functionality to restrict what a user sees in the UI based on their rights in the system.

When a user visits the site for the first time, there is a list item containing an administration menu that is hidden by default. When the user logs in successfully, the list item should now be shown if the user has the correct user rights. Here is the code of the li:

```
<li ng-show="isAdministrator">
... items here
</li>
```

On my controller I have the following code:

```
$scope.isAdministrator = authService.isUserAdmin;
```

At this point, if I console.log the authService.isUserAdmin value it is set to true, but the list item still does not show. If I manually refresh the page then the list item is shown. The reverse happens when I log out. Once I have logged out, the authService.isUserAdmin is set to false but the list item still shows until I refresh the page.

I can only assume that I am missing something very basic but I cannot find the problem. Just a quick side note, the code for the list is within a div that has the ng-controller set to the correct controller and the list has not yet been refactored into a directive.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: how do you set `isUserAdmin` in the `authService`?

Comment: $scope.isAdministrator = authService.isUserAdmin;

The authService is injected into the controller

Comment: @StevenMcD What is the code surrounding that? Best guess is the change isn't getting picked up by the $digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am sure that `$scope.isAdministrator = authService.isUserAdmin` execute before the `authService.isUserAdmin` executes

use this code:

in html:

```
<li ng-show="ser.isUserAdmin">
... items here
</li>
```

in controller:

```
$scope.ser= authService;
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this has to do with `authService.isUserAdmin` being a primitive type. Try this:

controller:

```
$scope.authServ = authService;
```

view:

```
<li ng-show="authServ.isUserAdmin">...</li>
```